# ASP.NET MVC: publish only selected view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have different look and feel (**not** a theme - but a completely different look and feel) for my ASP.NET MVC project. My customer can select which look and feel they want and I will publish it.

So far, I split each look and feel to different projects and they share the same code. Now, the number of look and feel has increased dramatically. There are over 30 different "look and feel" option to choose from. Yes, I have 30 different projects, all codes are exactly the same (including the javascript), except the View (cshtml) and the css files.

Is there an easy way to only publish a specific view? For example, I have the following view options:

- Modern
- Contemporary
- Classic
- Unique
- Andromeda

If my customer asked me that they want to use Modern "look and feel", then I will open the "Modern project" and publish it to their Azure server.

Any idea on how to use only 1 project and use something like "conditional publish"?

Thanks...

Comment: You can use Conditional Compilation.

Comment: Hi Anup, how to use conditional compilation to exclude certain view?

Comment: You can selectively exclude files or even the whole project for Different Compilation Configurations. But before I can answer, can you tell me how you are planning on keeping the files and folders? How is the folder structure going to be for views?

Comment: why don't you combine individual views in one view and control them based on environmental variable. For example, Project 1 - View 1 Project 2 - View 1, You can make only one project Main Project - View 1 in which you have If(Modern){ View 1 Code } else if(Contemporary) {view 2 code} and you can read which theme you want to load from Environmental variable. If your customer says change theme then just change variable value.

Comment: @Ingale88s, I love your idea... Add as an answer and I'll accept it... Thank you! Anup, since I haven't put them into 1 project yet, I am very flexible with the file structure. But I think Ingale88s has provided a perfect solution.

Comment: Glad I could help. Added as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine individual views in one view and control them based on an environmental variable.

```
For example, 
Project 1:
  View 1 
Project 2: 
  View 1
```

You can make one separate project

```
Main Project: 
  View 1
```

in which you have

```
If(Modern)
{ View 1 Code } 
else if(Contemporary) 
{view 2 code}
```

and you can read which theme you want to load from Environmental variable. If your customer says change theme then just change the variable value.

Comment: Thank you, this is a very clever trick! Thanks!